# GAN generator loss goes to zero

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am rather new to deep learning, please bear with me. I have a GAN, with model structure copy-pasted from: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-generative-adversarial-network-for-an-mnist-handwritten-digits-from-scratch-in-keras/

It will train for say 100-200 epochs with pretty ok results, then suddenly generator loss drops to zero... here is excerpt from log:

```
epoch,step,gen_loss,discr_loss
...
189,25,0.208,0.712
189,26,3.925,1.501
189,27,0.269,1.400
189,28,7.814,2.536
189,29,0.000,3.387 // here?!?
189,30,0.000,7.903
189,31,16.118,7.745
189,32,16.118,8.059
189,33,16.118,8.059
189,34,16.118,8.059
... etc, it never recovers
```

Is this a problem of vanishing gradients? Anything else I’m missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the blogpost comments people argues about the GAN's collapse problem, here you have a comment:

> There were problems with the discriminator collapsing to zero on occasions. This seems to be a known feature of GANs. Do any established GAN hacks help with this?
>   Looking at the discriminator after 100 epochs, it was in a confused state where everything passed into it was circa 50% probability real/fake. I colour coded some generated examples based on disriminator probability (red = fake, green = real, blue = unsure based on an arbitrary banding) and as you mentioned the subjective versus discriminator output does not always tie up. (example posted on linkedin). There was not enough spread in discriminator probability output to make this meaningful.

Comment: Oh deary, this is terribly embarrassing - I have completely overlooked that! So it *is* a known problem then.. In any case, thank you for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

GANs are very hard to train and it is very usual that the generator or the discriminator becomes so strong that the other can't improve itself, so if you for instance try to generate pictures I would recommend to use `progressive GANS` what improves the stability a lot and allow to go for high resolution images.